# rest-client gem with ruby

Tags: ruby, rest-client

So I am using rest-client gem and am able to get a response from my API request and the response is as follows:

`{"Invoice"=>[{"ReqKey"=>"9", "RequestID"=>"9B06C27E61BE4B8DB6B9", "SyncGuid"=>"D98013521663AE4E8251A327B0032A2C"}, {"ReqKey"=>"12", "RequestID"=>"E34FAB7ED5D74D30A61E", "SyncGuid"=>"9A01B67D186C0E4ABF787002624A97C5"}]}`

As you can see it is returning an array[2] of Invoice. My question is how do I determine the array size that is returned?

If it helps I am able to pull out values with the following but really need to how big the array is.

```
resp = $RESPONSE['Invoice'][0]
value = resp.fetch("ReqKey")
```

returns correct value 9

Another question: what format is this response?

Comment: how about `resp.values.map { |invoices| invoices.map { |invoice| invoice["ReqKey"] } }`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I answered my own question.
Randomly tried

```
resp2 = $RESPONSE['Invoices']['Invoice'].size
```

and it worked.

Would still like to know what format this technically is.